# VB.NET json select name

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I have a problem selecting a name.
I want to get `icons/icon_16x16.png` from `objects`. I already have done just that name.

My json:

```
{
    "objects": {
        "icons/icon_16x16.png": {
            "hash": "bdf48ef6b5d0d23bbb02e17d04865216179f510a",
            "size": 3665
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code to access this?

Comment: json is not just a fancy string; it is data to describe something which has been serialized.  Deserialize it or Parse it

Comment: You mean you want to access the `hash` and `size` properties?  Because the actual icon data doesn't seem to be there.